# Solving a nonlinear dynamical system using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I have been searching for many days for a way to solve following system using `NDSolve` in Mathematica. However, I have not gotten any result, any one can show how to solve it please...

The dynamical system is:

$$\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= a \cos{x+y} + b \sin{x+y}\\
\dot{y} &=  \frac{a [\cos{x} + \cos(x+y)] + b [\sin{x} + \sin{x+y}]}{\sin{y}}
\end{align*}$$

```
a = -1;b=2;
NDSolve[{x'[t] == a [Cos[x[t] + y[t]]] + b [ Sin [x[t] + y [t]]] / Sin [y[t]] ,
         y'[t] == [a [Cos[x[t]] + Cos [x [t] + y[t]] ] + b [ Sin [x[t]] + Sin [x[t] + y[t] ] ]]/ Sin [y[t]] ,
         x [0] == 0 , y[0] == 0.0001}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

where $x(0)=0$ and $y(0) = 0.1 \times 10^{-3}$

Comment: Post the Mathematica code, not just the LaTeX.

Comment: I do not know how to put the code on the post

a == -1, 2 == 0
NDSolve[{x'[t] == 
   a  [Cos[x[t] + y[t]]] + b  [ Sin [x[t] + y [t]]] / Sin [y[t]] , 
  y'[t] == [a [Cos[x[t]] + Cos [x [t] + y[t]] ] + 
      b  [  Sin [x[t]]  + Sin [x[t] + y[t] ] ]]/ Sin [y[t]] , 
  x [0] == 0 , y[0] == 0.0001}, {t, 0, 2}]

Comment: @MathGin You can have a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: @MathGin square brackets (`[` and `]`) are ***never*** used for grouping terms in algebraic expressions, since they are reserved for function application. So, an expression like $a[\cos x+\sin x]$ should be written as `a (Cos[x] + Sin[x])` in Mathematica.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not specify value for `b`. so I made one up.

```
ClearAll[x,y,t];
a=-1;b=2;
ode1=x'[t]==a*Cos[x[t]]+2*y[t]+b*Sin[x[t]];
ode2=y'[t]==(a*(Cos[x[t]]+Cos[x[t]+y[t]])+b*(2*Sin[x[t]]+y[t]))/Sin[y[t]];
ic={x[0]==0,y[0]==0.1*10^(-3)};
sol=NDSolve[{ode1,ode2,ic},{x,y},{t,0,1},
        Method->"StiffnessSwitching",AccuracyGoal->5,PrecisionGoal->4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

it is stiff system.